# Passing a list as an argument to another function

Tags: python, function, arguments

Create a list and calculate it's sum.

I have created a list in one function. I pass that list to a variable called v.
In the next function i created a function to return the sum of that list.

```
def list_generator(list_size):
  v = [int(input('Digit number\n')) for i in range(0,list_size)]
  return v

def list_sum():
  return sum(v)

list_size = int(input('Enter list size\n'))
v = list_generator(list_size)
print(list_generator(list_size))
print(list_sum())

#other code
def creat_list(list_size):
  v = [int(input('Digit number\n')) for i in range(0,list_size)]
  return v

def sum_list(v):
  return sum(v)

list_size = int(input('Digit list size\n'))
print(creat_list(list_size))
print(sum_list(v))
```

My code is executing two times the first function. Is there any way i can pass the list (v) to the other function in order to the program run as expected?

Comment: Why not just add it as a parameter like you did with the other function? `def list_sum(v)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate if i do that it gives erros saying my variable v is not defined

Comment: That doesn't show your code. [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: There's no difference between `list_generator` and `creat_list`. The difference is that you are assuming that `creat_list` sets a global variable that `sum_list` can use to resolve its free variable `v`; it doesn't.

Comment: I deleted my answer because this is getting too broad for the site. If you lookup tutorials on functions, you'll find many explanations around passing data between functions using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to store the returned result in a variable, like this:

```
v = creat_list(list_size)
print(v)
print(sum_list(v))
```

Notice that the `v` variable inside `creat_list` is *local* to the function and it won't exist outside the function once it returns.

Comment: did not i do that?

Comment: @LuísLopes No, you never saved the list in `v` in the second try.

Comment: No, you assigned the value in a local variable inside `creat_list`, that won't exist outside that function.

Comment: As I commented on the question, the only difference between `creat_list` and `sum_list` are in how you use (or don't use) the return value; the functions themselves are identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_generator(list_size):
  v = [int(input('Digit number\n')) for i in range(0,list_size)]
  return v
```

> It returns your list which in your case you have directly passed it in print() function without saving it for future use.

You can prefer saving it in a variable like this:

```
v = list_generator(list_size)
```

> you can then pass `v` as argument to your `list_sum` fun:

```
def list_sum(v):
  return sum(v)
```

You have been getting error `v` not defined in `list_sum` as v is neither a defined local variable for that particular function nor it is been passed as an argument

Answer (score -1):

Is this is what you want?

```
def list_generator(list_size):
  v = [int(input('Digit number')) for i in range(0, list_size)]
  return v


def list_sum():
  return sum(v)


list_size = 3
v = list_generator(list_size)
print(v)
print(list_sum())
```